# How can I prevent UI raycast from going through another Canvas?

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine, touch-event

I have a two canvas in a Scene and all `Canvas` are set to Screen Space mode camera render mode. The first `Canvas` is the main `Canvas` and has some buttons.The 'order in layer' property is 0.

The 2nd `Canvas` covers the whole area of the 1st `Canvas` . When you click some button on the first `Canvas`,the second `Canvas` will popup over the first `Canvas` (order in layer is 1).

The problem is that when I touch over 2nd canvas, the raycast also hit the 1st `Canvas`. How can I prevent the raycast from hitting the first `Canvas` while the 2nd `Canvas` (popup) is displayed on the screen?

Comment: Share your code/work around so other users can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second `Canvas` is a just a popup UI over the first one, you don't need to make it a `Canvas`. Make it a `Panel` instead. Select your first `Canvas`, right click then go to **UI**->**Panel**.You can also do this from **GameObject**->**UI**->**Panel**. Just make sure that your first `Canvas` is selected.

A new UI panel will be created inside the first `Canvas`. You can rename this to Popup panel then put all the UI components of the popup UI such as `Buttons` and `Texts` under the Popup panel. Use `popupPanel.SetActive(true);` to show the popup Window, and `popupPanel.SetActive(false);` to hide it.

Just drag the PopupPanel to the popupPanel slot in the script below, then you can use `showPopup()` and `hidePopup()` to control the popup panel.

```
public GameObject popupPanel;

void showPopup()
{
    popupPanel.SetActive(true);
}

void hidePopup()
{
    popupPanel.SetActive(false);
}
```

**EDIT :**

Make sure your popup `Panel` is at end of the `canvas` in hierarchy to make it render on top of everything else. This is the main idea of blocking interaction with others behind it.

Comment: @Umair M : Thank you for reply!! but 2nd canvas is a prefab, and it's also used in other scenes..

Comment: @zone1020 The same solution still apply. Redesign the 2nd canvas in a panel then make it a prefab. You can now put it under the first Canvas and use the solution I provided in my answer.

Comment: Thank you... I'll try it

Comment: sorry all is my fault, 2nd canvas bg image component's 'raycast target' property unchecked!!!

Comment: @zone1020 the 2nd canvas bg image component's 'raycast target' property is unchecked? If this is true then that's the problem. Although, the solution here should work. popup shouldn't be another Canvas. It should just be a Panel.